# OG Meta tags Facebook

Tags: jquery, facebook, facebook-opengraph

First of all, I searched how to change the meta tags of Open Graphics, and I managed to change them when the page loads.

This is inside the head section of the page.

```
<meta property="og:title" content="">
<meta property="og:image" content="">
<meta property="og:url" content="">
<meta property="og:type" content="blog" />
<meta property="og:site_name" content="Site Name">
```

And this occurs when the page is loaded with $(document).ready(); jQuery function (I saw in another question here, that : should be escaped with "\")

```
$("meta[property='og\:title']").attr("content", "Title changed" );
... and same for the rest of tags
```

Far away this works fine. But when the "Share" button is clicked doesn't shows the image, the title...

Tried the debug tool for this. https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/
but throws an error on the object URL (Object at URL 'http://my-link.com/' of type 'article' is invalid because the given value '' for property 'og:url' could not be parsed as type 'url'.)

I look the page source with firebug, and all the metatags are OK with all the information I given with jQuery.

What can I be doing wrong? I left them in blank in the main page (before loading the page it contains the jQuery) because no more pages will use it. May I just create them when I load the page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It makes zero sense to change those tags with JavaScript. Facebook does not run JavaScript - the only thing that matters is the value that's in the actual HTML code.

Comment: Oh, didn't know that. The point of that is because I got "Profiles", and I load them with Ajax, so I would like to share that "Profile", so that's why I thought to change the content of the tag.

Is there another way to make this then?

Comment: Only by making those profiles available under individual URLs, that supply the according meta data for each profile. (And that is of course something you should have done in the first place – develop a “normal” site structure, and only use AJAX afterwards to enhance it.)